# Stopping a keyboard from popping up from button presses

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have built a small tool that pushes text into a `<textarea>` with button inputs, you can [see it here](https://japanesekeyboard.net/)

However, on mobile, when a user interacts with those buttons, the keyboard pops up obscuring half the screen. Is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `readonly` attribute to the textarea.

Comment: So this works in that it stops the keyboard loading when tapping the buttons, however, it now blocks the user from being able to type with their keyboard when they need to. I kinda need it to do two things: When a user is using the buttons the keyboard doesn't show up, and when a user clicks the text area that keyboard shows up. Does this make sense?